# iOS: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftWebKit.dylib when using SwiftyDropbox from Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftWebKit.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

when I run my application which use my Cocoa Touch Framework where I added SwiftyDropbox framework using CocoaPods.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and to fix it I added `import WebKit` to the top of another file and the error went away. Apparently `WebKit` wasn't getting loaded in time or something. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution: deleted `libswiftWebKit.tbd` from linked Frameworks. I added it previously when upgrading XCode from version 11, but it's now no more required.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned, cleaned build folder and recompiled. That worked.